# Error within if statement conditional

Tags: java, arrays, list, conditional-statements

I'm building a program to work out the min, max and avg of the users input. 
When the user enters 0 or a negative number, the program exits the loop.

I'm currently working on building the input processor. But I'm having some errors. I haven't used conditionals to this extent before, so I must be making a mistake somewhere in there.

Also any suggestion for how I could make this better would be appreciated.

The error:

```
questionAvg.java:17: error: illegal start of expression
            if(input_into.nextInt() !=0) || input_into.nextInt < 0){
                                         ^
questionAvg.java:17: error: ';' expected
            if(input_into.nextInt() !=0) || input_into.nextInt < 0){
                                                                  ^
questionAvg.java:19: error: 'else' without 'if'
                } else{
```

The code:

```
import java.util.*; 
public class questionAvg
{
public static void main(String[]args)
{

Scanner input_into = new Scanner(System.in);
ArrayList<Integer> collector = new ArrayList<Integer>();

System.out.println("Enter 0 or a negative number to end input");
System.out.println("Enter a positive integer to populate the arraylist");


    while (input_into.hasNextint()){
                System.out.println("Type another int or exit");

            if(input_into.nextInt() !=0) || input_into.nextInt < 0){
                collector.add(input_into.nextInt());
                } else{
                        System.out.println("You entered 0 or a negative number. Now calculating....");
                }
            }
       }
  }
```

Comment: Three syntax errros errors: `input_into.hasNextint()){` -> `input_into.hasNextInt()){`, `if(input_into.nextInt() !=0) || input_into.nextInt < 0){` -> `if(input_into.nextInt() !=0 || input_into.nextInt() < 0){` (here are two)

Comment: the error actually tells you whats wrong. just keep staring at it untill you get it.

Answer (score 2):

You have a bracket in the wrong place, and you're treating `nextInt` as a public member variable not a method:

```
if(input_into.nextInt() !=0) || input_into.nextInt < 0)
```

needs to be:

```
if(input_into.nextInt() != 0 || input_into.nextInt() < 0)
```

as otherwise you're ending the if statement after the first condition hence all the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the extra `)` in the `if` statement before `||` and you also missed `()` while calling `input_into.nextInt() < 0`.It should be.

```
 if(input_into.nextInt() !=0 || input_into.nextInt() < 0){
```

And also you are reading integer twice in the `if(input_into.nextInt() !=0 || input_into.nextInt < 0)` and again in the next line `collector.add(input_into.nextInt());`.Instead you can do

```
  int inp=input_into.nextInt();
  if( inp!=0 || inp < 0){
                collector.add(inp);
```

Comment: OP also made an error in the second condition of the if statement: `input_into.nextInt` needs to be `input_into.nextInt()`

Comment: @jonk thanks updated my answer plus one for your sharp eyes

Answer (score 1):

You did mistake here :

```
if(input_into.nextInt() !=0) || input_into.nextInt < 0)
```

It should be

```
if(input_into.nextInt() !=0 || input_into.nextInt < 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following code (I have tested it):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class questionAvg {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner input_into = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Integer> collector = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        System.out.println("Enter 0 or a negative number to end input");
        System.out.println("Enter a positive integer to populate the arraylist");

        while (input_into.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.println("Type another int or exit");

            if ((input_into.nextInt() != 0) || (input_into.nextInt() < 0)) {
                collector.add(input_into.nextInt());
            } else {
                System.out.println("You entered 0 or a negative number. Now calculating....");
            }
        }
    }
}
```